# Installing and running LiipImagineBundle in symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, liipimaginebundle

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Added following in my composer.json:

   ```
   "require": {
        "imagine/Imagine": ">=0.2.8",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "*@dev",
        ....
        }
   ```
2. Ran following command at command line:

   ```
   composer update
   Installing imagine/imagine (v0.4.0)
   Installing liip/imagine-bundle (dev-master f7d5e4d)
   ```
3. After composer update my directory structure inside vendor folder looks like as below:

[image]

4. Then update vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php

   ```
    'Imagine'   => $vendorDir .'/imagine/Imagine/lib/',
    'Liip\\ImagineBundle'=>$vendorDir . '/liip/imagine-bundle/',
   ```
5. Registered bundle:

   ```
   new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
   ```
6. Routing:

   ```
   # app/config/routing.yml
   _imagine:
   resource: .
   type:     imagine
   ```
7. config.yml

   ```
     # app/config/config.yml
     liip_imagine:
     filter_sets:
        my_thumb:
           quality: 75
           filters:
              thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
   ```
8. Added to twig template file:

   ```
   <img src="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/images/1.jpg') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
   ```
9. Open localhost/symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/hello/test

There was no thumbnail image generation. When viewing the source I found the line:

```
  <img src="/symfony/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/my_thumb/symfony/web/bundles/acmedemo/images/1.jpg">
```

What I did I miss? Could somebody help me with this? I am using xampp 1.8 on windows xp with default settings

Comment: +1 For your installation instruction !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I replaced

```
 <img src="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/images/1.jpg') | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

with

```
 <img src="{{ 'bundles/acmedemo/images/1.jpg' | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

I got the thumbnail. I removed the asset() helper of twig and it worked but dont know how it worked.

Comment: Hi, I'm also using xampp and I've been through all the same steps as you but the image is still not being generated. Did you have to create your media/cache directory? No directories have bene created so I made them, still no images. Could it be a permission issue?

Comment: No you dont have to create media folder manually unless u dont have write permission or create directory permission. If you are on windows, this should not be the problem, but on linux, write permission is required. Read the doc under topic Configuration at https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle

Comment: I need to change the liip/imaginebundle and the imagine/imagine versions to those in you composer.json and update to make it work, thanks.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I was getting mad trying to make it work for me, turns out I just had to not use the asset() function.

Answer (score 1):

You might do: `<img src="{{ (asset('bundles/acmedemo/images/1.jpg')) | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />` because the filter filters the full image path and not only what asset() cointains, to mean you may also include the 'asset()'

Thanks