# Symfony2 LiipImagineBundle 'Failed to remove file'

Tags: image, caching, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I've installed LiipImagineBundle to Symfony 2 using this method - [Installing and running LiipImagineBundle in symfony 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107488/installing-and-running-liipimaginebundle-in-symfony-2-1)

I've done everything it asks and it initially creates the thumbnail image, however if I change the image dimensions in config.yml the image doesn't change!

I've tried clearing the cache using app/console cache:clear but I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                                                          
Failed to remove file /localhost/path/web//media/cache/my_thumb/media/test.jpg
```

Here is what my twig template looks like:

```
<img src="{{ asset(entity.filename) | imagine_filter('my_thumb') }}" />
```

It looks as though it can't remove the image in order to generate the new one, any ideas?

UPDATE:

Here is my routing file:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
_imagine:
resource: .
type:     imagine
```

Here is my config file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
  liip_imagine:
  filter_sets:
     my_thumb:
        quality: 75
        filters:
           thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

Comment: Ive updated my question. Basically this will initially create an image 120x90, however if I changed this to 180x190 it stays at 120x90. Also, does this only ever store one image? What if you wanted the same image in two different places which were different sizes? I.e a small image on a news listing page and a larger image on the main news article page.

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but there is a double slash in your path `/localhost/path/web//media/cache/my_thumb/media/test.jpg`, otherwise try to apply the same [permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) to your image directory as you did with the app/logs and app/cache folders.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it was the permissions as you suggested. I also have to clear the cache after I change the dimensions, is that correct yes? (Do you want to make your suggestion an answer and I'll set it as the correct answer to my question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to apply the same [permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) to your image directory as you did with the `app/logs` and `app/cache` folders.

You should then be able to clear the cache without any errors.
I haven't used the LiipImagineBundle yet, but i think it's best to clear the cache after each change to the dimensions, otherwise the bundle would have to check if the image was changed on each request (which defeats the purpose of caching)!

Hope this helps.